# nth-of-type not working as needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I am doing responsive website. My HTML code is as given below:

```
<h2>Title</h2>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<h2>Title</h2>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
```

CSS is like this:

```
.column-5{width:18.4%; margin-right:2%;}
.column-5:last-child{margin-right:0;}
```

and my JS like

```
$('.column_5:nth-of-type(5n+5)').addClass('last-child')
```

The output the above code currently produces is as follows:

```
<h2>Title</h2>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5 last-child">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<h2>Title</h2>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5 last-child">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5 last-child">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
```

However, what I am expecting/need is the below. Effectively, I need the `last-child` class to be added to every 5th consecutive element with the `column-5` class.

```
<h2>Title</h2>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5 last-child">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<h2>Title</h2>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5 last-child">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5 last-child">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `nth-of-type` is working as it is expected to. You would probably to have use a different method in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know this cannot be done with pure CSS because `nth-of-type` selector will not reset the counter when there is a different element in between. Also note that `nth-of-type` works primarily on the element type and not on the class selector you have attached to it.

Your current selector (`.column_5:nth-of-type(5n+5)`) would select the 5th element of every type which also happens to have the `class='column_5'`). It will work on all types of elements (that is, it will select all among the 5th `h2`, 5th `div`, 5th `span` as long as they have the required class). There is also a mismatch between the selector and the class in the HTML but I think it is a typo.

Your best bet would be to use JavaScript/jQuery to achieve this and below is a sample method using JavaScript (I assume you are Ok with a JS answer as it is tagged in question).

The code is pretty much self explanatory but I have added some inline comments for better understanding. It applies the class to every 5th element which has the required class (irrespective of the element type).

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var j = 0;
  var els = document.querySelectorAll('body *'); // Selecting all elements under parent but you can replace body with the required parent.
  for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) { // loop through all elements
    if (els[i].className.indexOf('column-5') != -1) { // if element has class
      j = j + 1; // increment counter
      if (j % 5 == 0) // if counter = 5 or its multiple
        els[i].className += ' last-child'; //add class
    } else { // if element does not have class
      j = 0; // reset counter.
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.last-child {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>Title</h2>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<h2>Title</h2>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
<div class="column-5">...</div>
```

---

**Response to comment:**

1. In your case each `section` element which has the class also has a child `img` element and so when we use a selector like `#id *` (descendant selector), it selects and traverses through all elements that are under the parent (irrespective of whether they are children, grand-children etc). So when the `img` tag is encountered, the counter `j` is getting reset. To avoid this, select just the direct children elements by using the below line:

   ```
   var els = document.querySelectorAll('.container > *');
   ```
2. In the fiddle, I have selected the **onDomReady** option in Frameworks & Extensions (sidebar). In your real code, you could either put this piece of code in a `script` tag just before the closing body tag (`</body>`) or if it is in a external script file, reference it at the same place (just before `</body>`).

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/69xmuj2h/6/)

Comment: thanks for the answer. Where should i paste this javascript either external or internal??

Comment: @KarthikN: You don't have any class named last-child in your CSS. :last-child is not a class. It is a pseudo. You should use .column_5.last-child. Also include the window.onload from the JS in the answer to be safe.

Comment: Update the same in http://jsfiddle.net/Karthik_Dev/69xmuj2h/.. But nothing works. Could you modify this fiddle...

Comment: It works :) Thanks a ton Harry... Nandri (Thanks in Tamil Language)... Hope you know :)

Answer (score 0):

Harry's answer is good. I also have an idea where we can still use nth-child concept. Wrap the blocks with another element. Like this:

```
<div class="blocks">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="column-5">...</div>
    <div class="column-5">...</div>
    <div class="column-5">...</div>
    <div class="column-5">...</div>
    <div class="column-5">...</div>
    <div class="column-5">...</div>
</div>
<div class="blocks">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="column-5">...</div>
    <div class="column-5">...</div>
    <div class="column-5">...</div>
    <div class="column-5">...</div>
    <div class="column-5">...</div>
    <div class="column-5">...</div>
    <div class="column-5">...</div>
    <div class="column-5">...</div>
    <div class="column-5">...</div>
    <div class="column-5">...</div>
    <div class="column-5">...</div>
    <div class="column-5">...</div>
    <div class="column-5">...</div>
    <div class="column-5">...</div>
    <div class="column-5">...</div>
    <div class="column-5">...</div>
    <div class="column-5">...</div>
    <div class="column-5">...</div>
</div>
```

Now you can use like ".blocks .column-5:nth-of-type(5n+5)').addClass('last-child')". Which means the children of .blocks will be counted and 5n+5 will work fine in every block.

Comment: Valid option as long as OP is fine with adding the wrapper block. By the way, I think you may have intended to type `nth-of-type` instead of `nth-child` in the first line.